# Will a consumer freezer survive air travel with a pressurization/depressurization cycle?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, cooling

Is it possible to ship a consumer freezer by air cargo (such as this one: https://www.danby.com/products/freezers/dcf072a2wp/ )? Or will the refrigerant gas expand too much and break the freezer? We all know a bag of chips cannot withstand air travel.

What are the risks to the freezer itself?

I am not talking about the hazmat implications (I know it is classified as a "dangerous goods": UN3358) but even if it is allowed on board, is it a good idea? or will the freezer be damaged by the pressurization/depressurization cycle?

Thank you!

transferred from here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/77810/will-a-consumer-freezer-survive-air-travel-with-a-pressurization-depressurizatio?noredirect=1#comment204081_77810

Answer (score 2):

The coils in any refrigeration system are designed to withstand a substantial pressure difference beyond ambient pressure.  It is common to see pressures approaching 200 psig on the high pressure side of these systems while in operation.  When your freezer is not in operation, the highest pressure inside the coils should be in the range of 50 psig or so.  Since a high altitude aircraft will only add approximately 1/2 of an atmosphere to that (e.g., 7 psi), the answer is "no", the pressurization/depressurization cycle will have no effect on the refrigeration coils.

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer!